# Can we call start method of a thread in run method of another thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

Can we call start method of a thread in run method of another thread?

This was asked in an interview. He said I have a thread A that extends thread class and I have B that extends thread class.

Can I call start method of thread b, I mean `b.start()`, in run method of A thread?

Please explain.

Comment: Can't you try that? It will take hardly 10-15 minutes, and probably you'll learn something else on the way.

Comment: Of course you can... Why don't you create a HelloWorld for yourself?

Comment: alright i will try and see..@RohitJain

Comment: Next time tell him that you would rather not extend `Thread` because that's abuse of inheritance. See top related question.

Answer (score 0):

I understand threads can be a bit weird in some cases but that one is fine I've been doing it for the past 2 years :)

Answer (score 0):

In a run method, you can do anything you want.

The only difference with any method, is that it may be invoked asynchronously, using the start() method of the class that contains it.